# In Array not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query where you search an array value.  I found a solution as to how to do this on Stackoverflow, however, it does not seem to give the output I would expect.  Here are the examples, can you tell me where I am going wrong please:

I have a table with a column called departments and some of the examples rows contain values like:

```
1: 2,4
2: 1,7,2,8,9,4
3: 4, 2
```

I run a query on this:

```
SELECT * FROM udf_multi_value WHERE udfdefid =  '1' AND department IN ( 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 4 );
```

This returns all rows in the results, which is what I would expect.  However, when I run:

```
 SELECT * FROM udf_multi_value WHERE udfdefid =  '1' AND department IN ( 2, 4 )
```

it only returns row 1 and 3.  As 2 and 4 are in all rows I wuld ave thought it should return row 2 as well.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normalize the tables? [Look into `FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: I should probably add that all rows have the udfdefid value of 1 so this is not the problem.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE udf_multi_value;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `udf_multi_value` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `registrantid` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
 `department` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
 `udfdefid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value` text NOT NULL,
 `isdefault` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 5):

Are those single fields with comma-separated values? If so, then you're getting expected behavior. You're passing in the integers `2` and `4`, and comparing them against char/varchar fields, e.g.

```
if (2 == '2,4')
and
if (4 == '2,4')
```

MySQL will convert the varchar field to an int, meaning `2,4` becomes int `2` and `4,2` becomes int `4`, so the matches succeed.

But `1,7,2,...` will be cast to just `1`, so there's no match.

You need to normalize your table so each of those numbers is in its own record in a sub-table, or use the MySQL non-standard SQL function [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
... AND (FIND_IN_SET('2', department) OR FIND_IN_SET('4', department))
```

Comment: Yup, this could work.  A little function to build the query each time.  I will give that a try.  Thanks.